# Is threre a list of available options for LayoutAnimation.Types and LayoutAnimation.Properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, layout-animation

I have checked the documentation and as now it only says

> create, config for animating in new views (see Anim type)
>
> update, config for animating views that have been updated (see Anim type)

The fact is that i dont understand what Anim type is and where im supposed to look after that. Thanks for the help

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it in the LayoutAnimation.js source code from react native

```
const TypesEnum = {
  spring: true,
  linear: true,
  easeInEaseOut: true,
  easeIn: true,
  easeOut: true,
  keyboard: true,
};


const PropertiesEnum = {
  opacity: true,
  scaleXY: true,
};
```

I might have missed something so feel free to add if there is more, thank you :)